# A Global variable to store the current user data in the current session

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies, session-variables, scope

last time I was checking about variables in asp.net, I have read that I should refrain using session variables, actually there's even an article talking
 about "session variable addicts" (:

I am still fresh web developer , and my situation is :

1. user enter application
2. page load:  I check cookies - if cookie exist = welcome the user.

   if no cookie - hand the user a proper registration form
3. user submits form - store user in cookies . set new record in database

ok so now there is a question, from this moment and **until user has exited the application**

for every request from this stage after cookie was set,

what am I suppose to choose:

1. check in every post if cookie exist
2. store user data in session and read from it on next click
3. no need to / none of the above

I will appreciate the correct informing answer ! thanks.

Comment: Why don't you use Forms authentication?

Comment: i guess i did not pay attention to the sugested solution, and i already constructed my logic around it(my code), also.. it will help me learn & better understand the process of page cycles ..and all around etc' and again i am using juery to validate form on client side , so from the begining the concept was a custom plan, and in short, i tend not to use ready solutions but i will seek some more information on how to implement the "Forms authentication" approach in my next project i might create a test project to cover this, though for now i do need to think on my case of scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, the ASP.NET membership provider works well for both user authentication as well as storing user profile data.  You can create a customer user profile object that stores user information/preferences (basically, any data unique to each user) that is then stored in the database and can be retrieved the next time the user logs on.

See the following link from Microsoft:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy(v=vs.100).aspx

And see the following about writing a custom profile class:
http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2008/01/19/writing-a-custom-asp-net-profile-class.aspx

Comment: nice articles i would get to implement it in my next project i guess.. thanks mate

Comment: I had gotten to the same point you were, already had a login system.  I finally made the decision it was worth it to backtrack and re-implement the login system via Membership.  There are functions that let you import existing users.  Ultimately, it was definitely worth it to go back and change over to using Membership for my project.